# iOS9 Navigation Bar Back Button not working

Tags: ios, iphone, back-button, ios9, navigationcontroller

Everything works perfectly before iOS 9.

However, when the app is running on iOS 9, nothing happens when back button is tapped so I am not able to go back as well as it keeps greyed out.

Also, I am not able to segue to the next view after the first segue.
For example, 
HomePage -> tap a button to segue to view 1 -> Segued to View 1 

-> tap on a button to segue to view 2 -> nothing happens

I uses the code below to perform segue,

```
UIViewController *push = 
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboard_id"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:push animated:YES];
```

**This issue only happens at iPhone 

but the app works flawlessly when running on a simulator**.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We need a special tag for "used to work up to iOS 8, breaks in iOS 9"! Seriously, seeing lots of questions that fall under this category... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem is solved.
I have been create a new project and use the same method to perform segue and it segued flawlessly. So I excluded the possibility of Xcode might cause the problem. And I found that I have passed the device token for apps at my app delegate by a NSRunLoop, I don't why it will cause such a weird problem, I decide to save the device token at NSUserdefault, then get it at the home page and parse it to server. So it works like a charm now after I take away the NSRunLoop now.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue (possibly the same).

For me the details are that I was building using Xcode 6.4 then testing on iOS 9.

Upgrading to Xcode 7 and iOS 9 SDK resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I upgrade my Xcode to 7.0 directly from 6.4,
I wonder if this will work after I do a clean and install of Xcode.
I will try that later, anyway, thanks!

Comment: Just clean and installed Xcode as well as clear all the derived data, but have no luck, still stuck on the back button, after the back button has no response after its tapped and it keeps at greyed out state. I doubt that does the back button is functional or do I need to config it manually for iOS 9? because its from the navigation item I dragged it from the scoreboard, it works perfectly with out any configuration before iOS 9.